# PHP: how to add associative keys to a numeric array... without deleting the numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array like this:

```
$result=array("1", "2", "34");
```

And I have another array:

```
 $keys=array("id", "price", "day");
```

As it is, `$result` has numeric keys for each of its values. I want to add to those values associative keys, using the values in `$keys` as such, but without deleting the numeric keys. That is, I want the result to be:

```
array(6)
{ [0]=> string(1) "1"
  [1]=> string(1) "2"
  [2]=> string(2) "34"
  ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["price"]=> string(1) "2"
  ["day"]=> string(2) "34"
}
```

I know that I could write a itty-bitty function to do this by hand, but is there any built-in function, among the myriad ones in PHP, to do this automatically? (My PHP knowledge is a bit rusty).

Comment: Use [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) - `$result = array_merge($result, array_combine($keys, $result));` though I don't understand why you need both enumerated and associative keys

Comment: But array_combine() doesn't save the numeric keys. It creates a new assoc. array with only the associative keys.

Comment: That's why he make an `array_merge` after the `array_combine`.

Comment: Aaahhh... with `array_merge` it's something different. That works.

Comment: @PaulJ - you must mean mysqli_fetch_array(), not mysqli_fetch_assoc(), the first returns both numeric and associative array.

Comment: @n-dru: yes, that's what I meant. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$result=array("1", "2", "34");
$keys = array("id", "price", "day");
$array = $result + array_combine($keys, $result);
```

If you considered using `array_merge`, I recommend this thread: [Array_merge versus +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059721/array-merge-versus)