# PHP Array combining not working

Tags: php, arrays

COMPANY ARRAY

```
array(1) { 
  [0]=> array(19) {
    ["entityid"]=> string(4) "3626" 
    ["entityparentid"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["entityduplicateof"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["entitytype"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["entityname"]=> string(12) "Facebook Inc"
  } 
}
```

DISTANCE ARRAY

```
array(1) { 
  ["distance"]=> string(4) "1.22" 
}
```

What I'd like the output to look like:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(19) {
        ["entityid"]=> string(4) "3626" 
        ["entityparentid"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["entityduplicateof"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["entitytype"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["entityname"]=> string(12) "Facebook Inc" 
        ["distance"]=> string(4) "1.22" // here
    }
}
```

***Question:***

`array_push($company_array,$distance_array);` seems to not do what I want it do.

It adds it to the end, but not where i want it to (notice the difference in where it is placed):

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(19) {
      ["entityid"]=> string(4) "3626" 
      ["entityparentid"]=> string(1) "0" 
      ["entityduplicateof"]=> string(1) "0" 
      ["entitytype"]=> string(1) "0" 
      ["entityname"]=> string(12) "Facebook Inc"
    },

    ["distance"]=> string(4) "1.22" // not here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has another level inside `$company`, if you want the single array inside that another nesting, point it to index zero directly, and use `array_merge`:

```
$company[0] = array_merge($company[0], $distance);
```

[Sample Output](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/fKZ3Jv)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to merge the two arrays is the `+` operator:

```
$company[0] = $company[0] + $distance;
```

A detailed explanation of the difference between `array_merge` and the `+` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059731/1902882).