# Edit array placement

Tags: php

I am having a simple issue with ordering an array elements.
Let's assume we have an array like this

```
[0]=>zero
[1]=>one
[2]=>two
[3]=>three
```

What i want is a way to move some elements to first position for example move one and two to first positions so i will have:

```
[1]=>one
[2]=>two
[0]=>zero
[3]=>three
```

and this should be done without knowing the current position of the element in the array which means it should be done by specifying the name of wanted element to move.
I thought about array_splice() but it won't work since i should specify the key of the element in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build two arrays (one with the searched values and one without) and merge them. Keep in mind that if you want to keep numeric keys, [you should use the `+` operator instead of `array_merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059721/array-merge-versus) :

```
<?php

$array = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three');
$searched_values = array('one', 'two');
$array_first = $array_second = array();

foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if (in_array($value, $searched_values))
        $array_first[$key] = $value;
    else
        $array_second[$key] = $value;
}

$array_end = $array_first + $array_second;

echo '<pre>'; print_r($array_end); echo '</pre>';
```

Returns :

```
Array
(
    [1] => one
    [2] => two
    [0] => zero
    [3] => three
)
```

**EDIT : Keeping the `$searched_values` order**

In this case, you just need to loop over the serached values in order to build an array of found values and simultaneously delete the initial array's entry :

```
<?php
    $array = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'); 
    $searched_values = array('one', 'three', 'two');
    $array_found = array();
    foreach ($searched_values as $key=>$value) {
        $found_key = array_search($value, $array);
        if ($found_key !== false) {
            $array_found[$found_key] = $value;
            unset($array[$found_key]);
        }
    }
    $array_end = $array_found + $array;
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($array_end); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Returns :

```
Array
(
    [1] => one
    [3] => three
    [2] => two
    [0] => zero
)
```

Comment: @roberto66 It's working fine but it has some issue like order of elements

Comment: <?
$array = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three');
$searched_values = array('one', 'three', 'two');
$array_first = $array_second = array();

foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if (in_array($value, $searched_values))
        $array_first[$key] = $value;
    else
        $array_second[$key] = $value;
}

$array_end = $array_first + $array_second;
print_r($array_end);
?>

Comment: Instead of outputing one three two zero it output one two three zero

Comment: It takes the initial order of `$array`. I'll try to work on a solution keeping `$searched_values` order. I'll get back to you in a jiff.

Comment: @Yassine I updated the answer, check the second code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is to remove it then add it:

```
$key = array_search('one', $array); // $key = 1;
$v = $my_array[$key];
unset($my_array[$key]);

array_unshift($my_array, $v);
```

Output:

```
[0] => one
[1] => zero
[2] => two
[3] => three
```

UPDATE:

If you use `array_unshift` it will not override your current element.