# Merging two keyed array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I've got two keyed arrays, say

```
$a = [ 'Arvind' => 'Basu', 'Rampal' => 'Singh' ];
```

and

```
$b = [ 'Anjali' => 'Basu', 'Roopashri' => 'Singh' ];
```

which I need to merge together in the format

```
$c = [ 'Arvind' => 'Basu', 'Anjali' => 'Basu' ,'Rampal' => 'Singh', 'Roopashri' => 'Singh' ];
```

(basically append the two arrays together and sorted according to surnames).

I've tried using the `array_merge` function to merge the two arrays, however, that dosen't seem to work.

Comment: Which is the surname? Key or value?

Comment: @Jeto - He wants them sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting appears to be a bit more complicated than it first appears. You want to sort first by value and then by key. You can use `array_multisort` for this.

```
<?php
$a = [ 'Arvind' => 'Basu', 'Rampal' => 'Singh' ];

$b = [ 'Anjali' => 'Basu', 'Roopashri' => 'Singh' ];

// You could also use `array_merge`. You should read about the differences.
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059731/296555
$c = $b + $a;

array_multisort(array_values($c), SORT_ASC, array_keys($c), SORT_ASC, $c);

var_dump($c);

array(4) {
  ["Anjali"]=> string(4) "Basu"
  ["Arvind"]=> string(4) "Basu"
  ["Rampal"]=> string(5) "Singh"
  ["Roopashri"]=> string(5) "Singh"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do. Here's a [sample](https://3v4l.org/st1Ma).

```
$a = [ 'Arvind' => 'Basu', 'Rampal' => 'Singh' ];
$b = [ 'Anjali' => 'Basu', 'Roopashri' => 'Singh' ];

$c = array_merge($a, $b);
ksort($c);
echo print_r($c);
```