# Merge 2 arrays having same number of items - php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, foreach

The number of items in both arrays `$newResponse` & `$key` will always be same.For each item of the `$newResponse`, i wanted to add items of `$key` to `$newResponse` in the same order they exists in `$key` array as mentioned in the **Expected result**.How can i achieve that?

`dump($newResponse);` is an array like below,which am getting as the result of a `foreach` loop.

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:6 [
    "courseId" => 18
    "courseDisplayName" => "qqq"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [
    "courseId" => 1
    "courseDisplayName" => "ips"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [
    "courseId" => 18
    "courseDisplayName" => "qqq"
  ]
  3 => array:6 [
    "courseId" => 1
    "courseDisplayName" => "ips"
  ]
]
```

`dump($key);` is an array like below, which is the result of another `foreach` loop.

```
array:4[
    0=>[
      "totalPoints" => 2
      "percent" => 1.0
      "id" => 2
    ]
    1=> [
      "totalPoints" => 10
      "percent" => 2
      "id" => 3
    ]
    2=> [
      "totalPoints" => 4
      "percent" => 0.0
      "id" => 6
    ]
    3=> [
      "totalPoints" => 4
      "percent" => 0.0
      "id" => 5
    ]
   ]
```

**Expected result**:

```
[
      [
        "courseId" => 18
        "courseDisplayName" => "qqq"
        "totalPoints" => 2
        "percent" => 1.0
        "id" => 2
      ]
      [
        "courseId" => 1
        "courseDisplayName" => "ips"
        "totalPoints" => 10
        "percent" => 2
        "id" => 3
      ]
      [
        "courseId" => 18
        "courseDisplayName" => "qqq"
        "totalPoints" => 4
        "percent" => 0.0
        "id" => 6
      ]
      [
        "courseId" => 1
        "courseDisplayName" => "ips"
        "totalPoints" => 4
        "percent" => 0.0
        "id" => 5
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: Did you try with a foreach?

Comment: [`This`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge) seems relevant.

Comment: @nice_devi know may be i can work it out with a foreach. But i don't know how to do that? can u show me the code?

Comment: @user1597430, i know programming basics, i was asking for help to know the logic of what to work out in the foreach loop here

Comment: @nice_devi tried the `merge()` method of collection as u mentioned in the link. i  put it inside the 2nd foreach loop i mentioned in orginal question. Then, it merges the 2nd array with only the first of of 1st array, not with all item of the 1st array in order.

Comment: This is a mega-duplicate question which I will hammering closed after a complete a comprehensive sweep of all duplicate pages on this topic.  In the meantime, this is most simply achieved with: [`array_map('array_merge', $newResponse, $key)`](https://3v4l.org/XYd9j)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

Assuming your data is:

```
        $newResponse = [
            [
                "courseId" => 18,
                "courseDisplayName" => "qqq"
            ],
            [
                "courseId" => 1,
                "courseDisplayName" => "ips",
            ],
            [
                "courseId" => 18,
                "courseDisplayName" => "qqq",
            ],
            [
                "courseId" => 1,
                "courseDisplayName" => "ips",
            ]
        ];

        $key = [
            [
        "totalPoints" => 2,
        "percent" => 1.0,
        "id" => 2
      ],
      [
        "totalPoints" => 10,
        "percent" => 2,
        "id" => 3
      ],
      [
        "totalPoints" => 4,
        "percent" => 0.0,
        "id" => 6
      ],
      [
        "totalPoints" => 4,
        "percent" => 0.0,
        "id" => 5
      ]
    ];
```

Then I'd probably reach for array_map, having used it for this kind of purpose recently:

```
        $out = [];
        array_map(function($a,$b) use (&$out) {
            $out[] = $a + $b;
        },$newResponse,$key);
        print_r($out);
```

Note in the above the `+` is very similar to array merge and I believe interchangeable in your use case. You can read about the difference here: [Array_merge versus +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059721/array-merge-versus)

Comment: Where should i keep this code? after both foreach loops?

Comment: @user17699125 yeah, after both foreach loops when your two arrays are fully populated.